# How to call a react hook on edit of registerBlockType?

Tags: block-editor

I'm registering a block:

block.js

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import Contents from './contents';
registerBlockType( 'spf/spf-design', {
    title: __( 'SPF Design', 'spf-design' ),
    icon: 'admin-users',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        images : {
            default: [],
            type:   'array',

        }
    },
    edit: Contents,
    save( { attributes, className } ) {
        // Gutenberg will save attributes we can use in server-side callback
       return null;
    },
} );
```

But it is giving me error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component.

The `Contents` is imported from another file.

contents.js

```
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';

export default function Contents() {

   const [name, setName] = useState( '' );
   const changeValue = (e) => {
        if (e.target.name == 'first-name') {
            setName(e.target.value);
        }
    }

    var element = 'Your Name:' +  name;
    element = [ ...element,  <input onChange={changeValue} type='text' name='first-name' /> ];

    return (
        element
    )
}
```

There seems to be some issue with using useState hook.

If I change contents.js to:

```
export default function Contents() {


    var element = 'Your Name:';
    element = [ ...element,  <input type='text' name='first-name' /> ];

    return (
        element
    )
}
```

It works fine. Can't I use `useState()` because it's been called from another hook?

Also, I found that contents.js standalone works fine with `useState()`.

Comment: I would need some more context. I'm replicating what you are doing by putting this in the browser's console, and when I add the block I do not get the error you mentioned:

```const Contents = () => { React.useState( 1 ); return null; }
wp.blocks.registerBlockType( "test/test", { edit: Contents, save: () => null, title: "Test" } );
```

Comment: Hey @Alexander, Thanks for looking into this. I've updated the question to provide more context. Can you please take a look when you get a chance?